# How To Add User Owner Bash Script in Ecex PHP?

Tags: php, linux

I have 2 same bash scripts. The first one is running via Ecex and the second one is running via Cronjob. But if both Bash scripts are run, permission is hit.

Bash Script 1 = Owner : UserA

Bash Script 2 = Owner : UserB

How do I get the bash script to have the same owner on the server?

Script 1 :

```
exec('/usr/local/zend/bin/php-cli /app/cli/clientBroadcast.php');
```

Script 2 :

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/php-cli /app/cli/clientBroadcast.php
```

Comment: You can change the owner on files in Linux using the [chown](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-chown-command/) command.

Comment: How to implement it into my bash script above ? sorry i don't understand linux

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chown` to the file or directory you want

For example

I assume you want to change both script files to userA

```
sudo chown userA Script-1-file
sudo chown userA Script-2-file
```